# HP laptop display stopped working

Tags: laptop, display, hp-pavilion, laptop-display

I have a problem regarding **HP Pavilion G6 Series** laptop.

The laptop's display stopped working.

**What have I tryed:**

- I have connected it to an external monitor via VGA cable and it is showing content.
- I have formatted the laptop and installed Windows, but the laptop's display is still not working.
- I have unplugged the display from the connectors and plugged them back in, but still no success.

I assume that the graphic card is OK, and that there is a problem in the LCD display.

What else can I try, to test what is wrong/needs to be changed, before I order a new LCD display? If I would need to order a new display, which display should I search for and how can I know if it is compatible with this laptop?

Comment: If you have to replace the display you should check what's the laptop exact model first, because **HP Pavilion G6 series** is [too generic](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/support-search.html?tab=2#/qryterm=HP%20Pavilion%20G6%20Series||&searchtype=s-001).

Comment: The laptop is **HP Pavilion G6 - 1125em**. Here is the [link](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=rs&dlc=en&docname=c02882607&lc=en&product=5141854&tmp_track_link=ot_search)

Comment: I found alot of them on eBay, by just entering the specification of the display, I guess that could work?

Comment: The graphic card is fine, otherwise you wouldn't be able to display anything on a external monitor. As @Battlefist suggested, you could try replacing the ribbon connector first, and then look for a new display. Whatever you end up doing, the [Maintenance and Service Guide](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/manualCategory?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5141854&) will come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one more thing that could go wrong.

Your display can be fine, but the **display connection ribbon** could be either disconnected from the motherboard or just broken and needing replacement.

In order to check you will need to buy a new display connection ribbon and disassemble your laptop.

Comment: I have disconnected and reconnected the ribbon in hope it would work, but it didn't. Before replacing the display I will order a new ribbon, to try if that was the case. The specifications for display are: **39,6 cm (15,6") High-Definition LED HP BrightView Display (1366 x 768)**. Is there a special display connection ribbon I should be looking for, or it's "generic"?

Comment: It should be rather generic. Btw. nothing stops you from unplugging it and taking up with you somewhere as you are going to replace display anyway if this replacing won't work. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to order a new display. You've done all the troubleshooting possible.

I would of done these things before ending my search

> I have connected it to an external monitor via VGA cable and it is showing content.
>
> I have unplugged the display from the connectors and plugged them back in, but still no success.

Which you have done already.